# Retrieve multiple values in delimited from XML using xquery

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

```
<Tasks>
 <Task>
  <UID>14</UID>
  <Name>Entertainment</Name>
  <ID>2</ID>
  <PerComp>22</PerComp>
  <Predecessor>
   <PredUID>12</PredUID>
   <PredType>1</PredType>
  </Predecessor>
 </Task>
 <Task>
  <UID>12</UID>
  <Name>Movie</Name>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <PerComp>55</PerComp>
  <Predecessor>
   <PredUID>13</PredUID>
   <PredType>1</PredType>
  </Predecessor>
  <Predecessor>
   <PredUID>14</PredUID>
   <PredType>1</PredType>
  </Predecessor>
 </Task>
 <Task>
  <UID>15</UID>
  <Name>Star</Name>
  <ID>3</ID>
  <PerComp>100</PerComp>
  <Predecessor>
   <PredUID>12</PredUID>
   <PredType>1</PredType>
  </Predecessor>
  <Predecessor>
   <PredUID>17</PredUID>
   <PredType>1</PredType>
  </Predecessor>
  <Predecessor>
   <PredUID>18</PredUID>
   <PredType>1</PredType>
  </Predecessor>
 </Task>
</Tasks>
```

Is it possible to capture all task ID'S and corresponding PredUID in comma separator using SQL `xquery`?

The basic `xquery` which we used returning values without delimiter.

Expected output:

```
14 12
12 13,14
15 12,17,18
```

Comment: What does "using sql xquery" refer to? Which database system that supports SQL and (usually only a very limited subset of) XQuery exactly are you using? Is the `string-join` function supported?

Comment: I am completely new to xml parsing in mssql. Looking for all possible ways to retrieve values in comma delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this XQuery expression:

```
for $tsk in doc('input.xml')/Tasks/Task 
return concat($tsk/UID,' ', string-join($tsk/Predecessor/PredUID,','),'&#xa;')
```